# How to increase worker_process nginx directadmin

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, webserver, directadmin

I want increase worker_process in Nginx installed on DirectAdmin,
and i open this file:

```
nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

but it have no Worker_process, below is all codes:

```
#user  nginx;

# The number of worker processes is changed automatically by CustomBuild, according to the number of CPU cores, if it's set to "1"

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
#    worker_connections 1024;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-events.conf;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # For user configurations not maintained by DirectAdmin. Empty by default.
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-includes.conf;

    # Supplemental configuration
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-modsecurity-enable.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-gzip.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-ips.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-settings.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-vhosts.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-vhosts.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable following line and increase it which you want.

```
#    worker_connections 1024;
```

Comment: when i enable it, nginx cant restart and show me failed